# How do i get values from an array java

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently having trouble pulling certain values from an array, as it stands my array code is as follows:

```
private List<FootballPlayer> getData() {

    List<FootballPlayer> theData = new ArrayList<FootballPlayer>();

    // create a Scanner and grab the data . . .

    Scanner scanner = null;

    String dataPath = dbLocation + File.separator + "text" + File.separator + "players.db";

    String imagePath = dbLocation + File.separator + "images";

    try {

        scanner = new Scanner(new File(dataPath));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) { 

        System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());


        System.exit(0);
    }

    // scan player.db file line-by-line

    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        String line = scanner.next().trim();

       // trim used to trim for new line

        String[] bits = line.split(":");

        String t = bits[0];                    // title
        String imgFileName = bits[1];          // image file name
        int pa = Integer.parseInt(bits[2]);     // pace
        int sh = Integer.parseInt(bits[3]);     // shooting
        int dr = Integer.parseInt(bits[4]);    // dribbling
        int ph = Integer.parseInt(bits[5]);    // physical

        // create the image

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(imagePath + File.separator + imgFileName);

        // Create the business object

        FootballPlayer player = new FootballPlayer(t, img, pa, sh, dr, ph);

        // add it to the list ... simple as ...

        theData.add(player);
    }

    scanner.close(); 

    return theData;

}
```

From players.db file like this:

```
Pique:DFPique.png:66:60:54:76
Ramos:DFRamos.png:79:66:60:82
Maldini:LEGMaldini.png:86:67:56:80
Pele:LEGPele.png:95:94:89:73
DiMaria:MFDiMaria.png:90:87:79:71
Neymar:MFNeymar.png:90:92:80:58
Berahino:STBerahino.png:81:70:69:55
Ronaldo:STRonaldo.png:98:99:99:89
```

I'm unsure on how to pull say the image path (.png) from the array within another class if for example Ramos is selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your question is. Would you like to know how to get a specific FootballPlayer object with a given player name? Or is the problem about accessing the image inside the FootballPlayer object?

Comment: If you want to use your 'theData' ArrayList in another class, make your 'getData()' method public. Then call the method from any other class and loop through the 'theData' reference to get the values.

Comment: @prudhvi then it would be opening and parsing the file every time the data was wanted, when that (presumably) only needs to be done once

Answer (score 0):

First: this is not an array, but a List.

Second: you'll probably need a finder method:

```
public FootballPlayer findPlayerByName(List<FootballPlayer> players, String name) {
  for (FootballPlayer player: players) {
    if (player.getName().equals(name)) {
      return player;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```